# Tensor multiplication w/o looping in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, tensor

I have a 3d array A, e.g. A=rand(N,N,K).

I need an array B s.t.

```
B(n,m) = norm(A(:,:,n)*A(:,:,m)' - A(:,:,m)*A(:,:,n)','fro')^2 for all indices n,m in 1:K.
```

Here's the looping code:

```
B = zeros(K,K);    
for n=1:K
       for m=1:K
           B(n,m) = norm(A(:,:,n)*A(:,:,m)' - A(:,:,m)*A(:,:,n)','fro')^2;
       end
end
```

I don't want to loop through 1:K.

I can create an array An_x_mt of size N*K x N*K s.t.

```
An_x_mt equals A(:,:,n)*A(:,:,m)' for all n,m in 1:K by
An_x_mt = Ar*Ac_t;
```

with

```
Ac_t=reshape(permute(A,[2 1 3]),size(A,1),[]); 
Ar=Ac_t';
```

How do I create an array Am_x_nt also of size N*K x N*K s.t.

```
Am_x_nt equals A(:,:,m)*A(:,:,n)' for all n,m in 1:K
```

so that I could do

```
B = An_x_mt  - Am_x_nt
B = reshape(B,N,N,[]);
B = reshape(squeeze(sum(sum(B.^2,1),2)),K,K);
```

Thx

Comment: "I don't want to loop through 1:K." Why not? Have you determined this is a bottleneck in your code? Are you sure it would be faster without the loop? Anything you do with `reshape` and `permute` will be more difficult to read than the loop, and hence more costly to maintain.

Comment: Yes, this is a major bottleneck. Array multiplications are much faster

Comment: This is the Frobenius norm http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html
Sum of squared absolute values of the matrix

Comment: The question is how to claculate Am_x_nt(n,m) = A(:,:,m)*A(:,:,n)' without looping.

Comment: See [mmx](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37515-mmx) or [`mtimesx`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977).

Comment: Took some fiddling to build mmx, but it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't/won't use mmx and want to stick to pure Matlab code, here's how you could do it. mat2cell and cell2mat functions are your friends:

```
[N,~,nmat]=size(A);
Atc = reshape(permute(A,[2 1 3]),N,[]); % A', N x N*nmat
Ar = Atc'; % A, N*nmat x N
Anmt_2d = Ar*Atc; % An*Am'
Anmt_2d_cell = mat2cell(Anmt_2d,N*ones(nmat,1),N*ones(nmat,1));
Amnt_2d_cell = Anmt_2d_cell'; % ONLY products transposed, NOT their factors
Amnt_2d = cell2mat(Amnt_2d_cell); % Am*An'
Anm = Anmt_2d - Amnt_2d;
Anm = Anm.^2;
Anm_cell = mat2cell(Anm,N*ones(nmat,1),N*ones(nmat,1));
d = cellfun(@(c) sum(c(:)), Anm_cell); % squared Frobenius norm of each product; nmat x nmat
```

Alternatively, after computing Anmt_2d_cell and Amnt_2d_cell, you could convert them to 3d with the 3rd dimension encoding the (n,m) and (m,n) indices and then do the rest of the computations in 3d. You would need the permn() utility from here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn-v-n-k

```
Anmt_3d = cat(3,Anmt_2d_cell);
Amnt_3d = cat(3,Amnt_2d_cell);
Anm_3d = Anmt_3d - Amnt_3d;
Anm_3d = Anm_3d.^2;
Anm = squeeze(sum(sum(Anm_3d,1),2));
d = zeros(nmat,nmat);
nm=permn(1:nmat, 2); % all permutations (n,m) with repeat, by-row order
d(sub2ind([nmat,nmat],nm(:,1),nm(:,2))) = Anm;
```

For some reason, the 2nd option (3D arrays)  is twice faster.

Hopes this helps.