# Multiply n vectors of length p by n matrices of size pxp

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, complex-numbers, tensor

I have `n` complex vectors of length `p` that I want to multiply by `n` complex matrices of size `p`-by-`p`. I am looking for the most efficient way to do this in MATLAB. If it matters, I am imagining that n is large and p is small.

An example using a loop (which I would like to avoid) is shown below.

```
N = 1e4;
p = 5;
A = randn(p, N); % N vectors of length p
B = randn(p, p, N); % N matrices of size pxp

C = zeros(p, N); 
for k = 1:N
    C(:, k) = B(:, :, k) * A(:, k);
end
```

It's been suggested that I might be able to achieve this efficiently using tensor functions, but I haven't been able to figure that out.

Comment: See the related question (and my comment on it) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916104).

Comment: Thanks, Dev-iL, this is really helpful. I was able to get things working with MTIMESX (and it's a lot faster in this example). In general, however, the matrices/vectors will be complex, and my understanding is that both MTIMESX and MMX perform substantially more poorly with complex numbers. Are you aware of a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first question

Comment: There was a contributor on GitHub that attempted to add some [limited support for complex matrices](https://github.com/yuvaltassa/mmx/pull/2) (however, if you're using R2018a or newer that wouldn't work). I suppose that if you insist on using these libraries, it'll force you to pass the real and imaginary parts separately (i.e. something like: `mmx(real_x, real_y) - mmx(imag_x, imag_y) + 1i *( mmx(real_x, imag_y) + mmx(imag_x, real_y) )`) - and this is probably inefficient compared to [Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487752/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using [implicit expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/):

```
C = permute(sum(B.*permute(A, [3 1 2]), 2), [1 3 2]);
```

For old Matlab versions (before R2016b) you need to rewrite it with [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
C = permute(sum(bsxfun(@times, B, permute(A, [3 1 2])), 2), [1 3 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that in various ways:

```
A = rand(3, 3, 1e6);
B = rand(3, 1);
tic, C = zeros(3, size(A, 3));
for i = 1:size(A, 3)
  C(:,i) = A(:,:,i)*B ;
end, toc
tic; C = reshape(reshape(permute(A,[2,1,3]),3,[]).'*B,3,[]); toc
tic; C = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, reshape(B, 1, 3)), 2)); toc
```

In my system:

```
Elapsed time is 2.067629 seconds.  % Loop
Elapsed time is 0.064164 seconds.  % permute
Elapsed time is 0.145738 seconds   % sum(times())
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solution only shows how to multiply *one* vector of length p by N different matrices. My question is asking how to do this if you have N different vectors. Note that in my solution A is pxN and B is pxpxN, whereas in your solution A is pxpxN but B is only px1. (You switched A and B, but that isn't the issue.)